# I cannot get the different values from radio buttons using jquery ajax

Tags: jquery

my form

```
<form action="" method="post">

<p>Shirt 1 : <input type="radio" name="myradio" id="myradio" value="0"/></p>
<p>Shirt 2 : <input type="radio" name="myradio" id="myradio"  value="1"/></p>


<input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" value="create" onclick="createImage()" />

</form>
```

my javascript:

```
function createImage(){

     $.ajax({


        type: "POST",
        url: "output.php",
        data:   "myradio=" + document.getElementById("myradio").value,
        success: function(html){
            $("#output").html(html);
        }   


     });
}
```

for `$_POST['myradio']` I'm only getting the value of 0 even if I click the 2nd radio button. Do I need to give the radio buttons different id's?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `:checked` selector. This will give you the checked radio button. Also, `ID`s should be ***unique*** in a page. My example here uses class `myradio`.

```
data:   "myradio=" + $(".myradio:checked").val(),
```

---

another elegant way is to use `.serialize()`. This will give you the string param for submission.

in your example, if we use `.serialize()`, we can get something like `myradio=0` if `myradio` with a value of zero is checked.

sample code, try it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/GUEwY/)

```
$(function(){
    $(':button').click(function() {
        alert($('form').serialize());
        return false;
    });
});
​
```

Comment: small typo, `checked`.  But same thing I was gonna say -- I take it back, already fixed ;o)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 $('input:radio[name=myradio]:checked').val();
```

instead of this:

```
document.getElementById("myradio").value;
```